# How to write multiple data in a single row in new column in existing csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My data frame is:

```
message         
['Hi', 'RAM RAM RAM', 'MAHESH MAHESH']
```

My desired output is:

```
message                                 count
['Hi', 'RAM RAM RAM', 'MAHESH MAHESH']  RAM:3, MAHESH:2
```

I have tried to write the data in CSV using python but I am not able to write multiple data in the count column. So please help me if there is any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is extremely unclear, severely lacking in detail... That “data frame”, which doesn’t really look like a DataFrame, is identical to your desired output. You say you tried to write the data to CSV, but don’t provide any code that we could debug, and then reference a `count` column which is meaningless because, again, we don’t have the code. On top of aaaall that, I’m sure you can find a bajillion solutions both on Stack Overflow and all over the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'message':[['HI', 'RAM RAM RAM', 'MAHESH MAHESH']]})
df
                            message
0  [HI, RAM RAM RAM, MAHESH MAHESH]

df['count'] = df['message'].apply(' '.join).str.split().apply(Counter)
df
                            message                             count
0  [HI, RAM RAM RAM, MAHESH MAHESH]  {'HI': 1, 'RAM': 3, 'MAHESH': 2}
```

Comment: I don't want the count of all string of list ['HI', 'RAM RAM RAM', 'MAHESH MAHESH']. I have a list of string-like ['string'] and i have to count the string as matched to string of list.

Comment: then give a better example